# Replacing a specific piece of a name attribute using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace some text when I press the submit button on my page with an incrementing integer value.

```
<input type="text" id="peerSubscription[peerEventSubscriptions][REPLACE_THIS_ON_PERSIST][maxThreshold]" name="peerSubscription[peerEventSubscriptions][REPLACE_THIS_ON_PERSIST][maxThreshold]" required="required" placeholder="Max" highlight_from="min" hover_error="1" rel="slider" min="0" max="1000" step="100" prefix="" suffix="" divisor="1" class="form-control" value="500">
```

Where is reads:

```
REPLACE_THIS_ON_PERSIST
```

I want to be replaced with an incrementor that adds 1 on each iteration of this name attribute that it finds on the page.

Comment: Is your site refreshing on submit?

Comment: Yes the page refreshes on submit. I just need the values to change for the sake of the submission.

Comment: You will need to also submit the values, and changing the ID on load.

Comment: If this ID needs to increase permanently for every user, you will have to submit it, if it needs to increase permanently for each user, you will have to submit it either. If this ID may be volatile, you should take a look at `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`. They may be useful for what you need.

Comment: @Ryan If you check my updated answer, it should give you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways you could do this, you could use `localstorage` or you could use `sessionStorage`.

`localStorage` and `sessionStorage` both extend Storage. There is no difference between them except for the intended "non-persistence" of `sessionStorage`.

That is, the data stored in `localStorage` persists until explicitly deleted. Changes made are saved and available for all current and future visits to the site.

For `sessionStorage`, changes are only available per window (or tab in browsers like Chrome and Firefox). Changes made are saved and available for the current page, as well as future visits to the site on the same window. Once the window is closed, the storage is deleted.

So below in my code it shows on button click, check for `localstorage`, if no `localstorage` then replace `[REPLACE_THIS_ON_PERSIST]` with `[submission=" + counter + "]` and create `localstorage`.

**Local Storage:** `localStorage.setItem("submission", counter);`

Then on the second button click it will check for the localstorage and then will keep on adding the counter on each click.

**Example:**

`id='peerSubscription[peerEventSubscriptions][submission=1][maxThreshold]'`
`id='peerSubscription[peerEventSubscriptions][submission=2][maxThreshold]'`
`id='peerSubscription[peerEventSubscriptions][submission=3][maxThreshold]'`

[**JSFiddle Example (Shows how to do it by `ID` and `name` attributes)**](http://jsfiddle.net/1fgfx5yk/4/)

**Code (Shows only by `ID` attribute):**

```
var counter = 0;

if (localStorage.submission) 
{      
    counter = localStorage.submission;
    if ($("input[id*='[REPLACE_THIS_ON_PERSIST]']"))
    {
        $("input[id*='[REPLACE_THIS_ON_PERSIST]']").each(function()
        {
            var select = $(this);
            select.replaceWith("<input type='text' id='peerSubscription[peerEventSubscriptions][submission=" + localStorage.submission + "][maxThreshold]' name='peerSubscription[peerEventSubscriptions][REPLACE_THIS_ON_PERSIST][maxThreshold]' required='required' placeholder='Max' highlight_from='min' hover_error='1' rel='slider' min='0' max='1000' step='100' prefix='' suffix='' divisor='1' class='form-control' value='500'>");
        }); 
    }
}

$("#buttonTest").on('click', function () 
{
    if (localStorage.submission) 
    {                         
        $("input[id*='submission=" + localStorage.submission + "']").each(function()
        {
            var select = $(this);
            counter++;
            localStorage.setItem("submission", counter);
            select.replaceWith("<input type='text' id='peerSubscription[peerEventSubscriptions][submission=" + localStorage.submission + "][maxThreshold]' name='peerSubscription[peerEventSubscriptions][REPLACE_THIS_ON_PERSIST][maxThreshold]' required='required' placeholder='Max' highlight_from='min' hover_error='1' rel='slider' min='0' max='1000' step='100' prefix='' suffix='' divisor='1' class='form-control' value='500'>");
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $("input[id*='[REPLACE_THIS_ON_PERSIST]']").each(function()
        {
            counter++;
            var select = $(this);
            // Store
            localStorage.setItem("submission", counter);

            select.replaceWith("<input type='text' id='peerSubscription[peerEventSubscriptions][submission=" + counter + "][maxThreshold]' name='peerSubscription[peerEventSubscriptions][REPLACE_THIS_ON_PERSIST][maxThreshold]' required='required' placeholder='Max' highlight_from='min' hover_error='1' rel='slider' min='0' max='1000' step='100' prefix='' suffix='' divisor='1' class='form-control' value='500'>");
        }); 
    }
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

**Example:**

[**JSFIDDLE Example (sessionStorage)**](http://jsfiddle.net/1fgfx5yk/5/)

**Code:**

```
var counter = 0;

if (sessionStorage.getItem("submission")) 
{      
    counter = sessionStorage.getItem("submission");
    if ($("input[id*='[REPLACE_THIS_ON_PERSIST]'], input[name*='[REPLACE_THIS_ON_PERSIST]']"))
    {
        $("input[id*='[REPLACE_THIS_ON_PERSIST]'], input[name*='[REPLACE_THIS_ON_PERSIST]']").each(function()
        {
            var select = $(this);
            select.replaceWith("<input type='text' id='peerSubscription[peerEventSubscriptions][submission=" + sessionStorage.getItem('submission') + "][maxThreshold]' name='peerSubscription[peerEventSubscriptions][submission=" + sessionStorage.getItem('submission') + "][maxThreshold]' required='required' placeholder='Max' highlight_from='min' hover_error='1' rel='slider' min='0' max='1000' step='100' prefix='' suffix='' divisor='1' class='form-control' value='500'>");
        }); 
    }
}

$("#buttonTest").on('click', function () 
{
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('submission')) 
    {                         
        $("input[id*='submission=" + sessionStorage.getItem('submission') + "']").each(function()
        {
            var select = $(this);
            counter++;
            sessionStorage.setItem("submission", counter);
            select.replaceWith("<input type='text' id='peerSubscription[peerEventSubscriptions][submission=" + sessionStorage.getItem('submission') + "][maxThreshold]' name='peerSubscription[peerEventSubscriptions][submission=" + sessionStorage.getItem('submission') + "][maxThreshold]' required='required' placeholder='Max' highlight_from='min' hover_error='1' rel='slider' min='0' max='1000' step='100' prefix='' suffix='' divisor='1' class='form-control' value='500'>");
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $("input[id*='[REPLACE_THIS_ON_PERSIST]'], input[name*='[REPLACE_THIS_ON_PERSIST]']").each(function()
        {
            counter++;
            var select = $(this);
            // Store
            sessionStorage.setItem("submission", counter);

            select.replaceWith("<input type='text' id='peerSubscription[peerEventSubscriptions][submission=" + counter + "][maxThreshold]' name='peerSubscription[peerEventSubscriptions][submission=" + counter + "][maxThreshold]' required='required' placeholder='Max' highlight_from='min' hover_error='1' rel='slider' min='0' max='1000' step='100' prefix='' suffix='' divisor='1' class='form-control' value='500'>");
        }); 
    }
});
```

Comment: @sailens It could work, because he might be refreshing the page each time. So that the value will be reset to `[REPLACE_THIS_ON_PERSIST]` and he'd keep changing the `ID` before each submission. (Not best practise I know but it's one way of doing it) or like you said in your comment above on his question, he will need to submit the new ID with each submit, then load it on page refresh.

Comment: He can always use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` to avoid submitting it. We don't know much about the use of that ID

Comment: @sailens Yes, you are correct. I've updated my answer to show what we are talking about.

Comment: Can you recommend session storage to the op as well. Since local storage persists on browser close

Comment: @Jesse I've updated my answer to provide information on both `localstorage` and `sessionStorage`